# DataGrip added value compared to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: database, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

So, I was wondering if there is really some new features coming from JetBrains [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) software.

So far, I didn't find anything that is not already there in IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate). I didn't spend much time using it though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**OBSOLETTE:**

In 2016.3 there's a feature that is DataGrip specific

> Tracking database changes
>
> If there are lots of changes in many places, you can see all of them
> from the Database Changes window. Important! This window is available
> only in DataGrip, but not in other IntelliJ-based IDE's.

https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/

Comment: As of July 2017, the DataGrip team confirms that this is the only difference: Thanks. I will point to this at stackoverflow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4889#comment=27-2337064

Comment: 2018.1 Release Candidate adds the Database Changes window to Ultimate.

Answer (score 30):

I am Max, the PMM of DataGrip.

We usually say that DataGrip provides the same functionality as all the other IDE's from JetBrains with the database support. As mentioned above, DataGrip provides better user experience as a standalone IDE.

Comment: Database changes is now added to al IDEs as well

Comment: Does this holds at 2020.07?

Comment: Hey @moscas - just a quick Q as a long time user of PHPStorm, why should I pay £69 to buy Datagrip when its virtually built in to Storm? If you did a 50% discount to anyone with a qualifying IDE, I'd buy it at that level, but £70? na. Unless you had inline debugging of mySQL stored procedures, oh hell I'd be throwing my money at you! ;)

Comment: It's a fair point and we are thinking about this. On the other hand we do know many users who are purchasing DataGrip in this situation for the better usability.

Answer (score 9):

From FAQ part from this [blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2015/12/16/datagrip-1-0-formerly-0xdbe-a-new-ide-for-dbs-and-sql/).

> *Does DataGrip repeat the functionality of the database tools in other JetBrains IDEs?*
>
> Yes, the first version focuses on that core functionality.

Further dialog from comments:

> `Graham says`:
>
> December 16, 2015 at 10:01 pm
>
> *This repeats the functionality in Intellij, but does it add any more features over and above Intellij? If they are equal right now, will that always be the case? Would be nice to see a feature comparison chart.*
>
> ---
>
> Reply
>
> `Andrey Cheptsov says`:
>
> December 17, 2015 at 8:03 am
>
> *The latest version of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate includes the functionality of DataGrip 1.0. Still, **DataGrip is focused on working with databases and SQL and thus may provide better user experience as a standalone IDE**.*

Comment: Is this still accurate today in the beginning of 2023?

Answer (score 1):

### Since 2018.1 RC InetlliJ (Ultimate) supports everything DataGrid supports, but:

1. MongoJS support. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=datagrip
   [image: Compare-InelliJ-vs-DataGrid]